# sem_timedwait() for specific time

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, semaphore

i Want to wait on semaphore for 20 mili-secound as below,but when i am printing values of tv_sec and tv_nsec getting very big values.

Can anybody will help to understand this below code.

```
if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts) == -1)
    {
        //throw error
    }
ts.tv_nsec += 20000000;
ts.tv_sec += ts.tv_nsec / 1000000000;
ts.tv_nsec %= 1000000000;

sem_timedwait(&semaphore, &ts)
```

Comment: `printf` is not instantaneous, so may be that's the reason.

Comment: What are these big values? `tv_sec` around 1.4 billion and `tv_nsec` below 1 billion?

Comment: What do you consider a "billion". "billion" is ambigious among different lanuages. `10**9` or `10**12`?

Answer (score 1):

It should be big. 
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts) gives the ticks since Epoch time and you are adding to that returned values.

From the http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html manual page.

> All implementations support the system-wide realtime clock, which is identified by CLOCK_REALTIME. Its time represents seconds and nanoseconds since the Epoch. When its time is changed, timers for a relative interval are unaffected, but timers for an absolute point in time are affected.

From sem_timedwait(3) - Linux man page

```
int sem_timedwait(sem_t *sem, const struct timespec *abs_timeout);
```

The abs_timeout argument points to a structure that specifies an absolute timeout in seconds and nanoseconds since the Epoch

Answer (score 0):

1. `clock_gettime` retrieves the current "date and time" in a specific format
2. Operations on `timespec` structure are updating this date : current date + 20ms (and it tries to handle a border effect: if the `nsec` "overflows" then we should increment the `sec`): so after that `ts` contains the deadline for your semaphore
3. Semaphore waits for a `sem_post` or a timeout.